# Resoning on Terms if reused by refering to their URIs

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

I want to reuse existing vocabulary. Instead of importing whole ontologies, I want to do it by referring to URIs of selected classes and properties in my ontology.

If ontologies are imported then axioms are also imported in my ontology, so reasoner obviously will take care of the imported axioms.
But if I reuse classes/properties by referring to their URIs then axioms are not imported in my ontology. So, My question is that  will the reasoner respect the rules applied on the referred terms?

====
Added Later

instead of copy past or OWL Import if terms are reused by referring to their URIs then axioms are not imported into target ontology.

But my question is that if internet is available then will the reasoner Fitch and respect axioms applied to that specific (reused) term.

for example, if I am reusing [nfo:fileSize](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo/#fileSize) by referring to semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo/#fileSize , so if in case I am connected to internet then will reasoner go over internet to check for the axioms applied to nfo:filesSize?

Comment: If the reasoner doesn't know the rules, how could it possibly respect them?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, reasoners are not expected to find out more axioms online if presented with the IRI of a class or property. They are meant to use all and only the axioms in the import closure of their ontology.

However, there are other ways of including only part of an ontology into a new ontology, for the purpose of reusing classes and properties with their original meaning. There are techniques such as modularisation and atomic decomposition that allow you to select a subset of the axioms of an ontology, e.g., all the axioms used in defining a specific class - which you can then copy over.

Comment: So it means that reusing terms by referring to their URIs has disadvantage that reasoner will not be able to reason on rules/axioms applied on the refereed term. if this is the case then we can say that reusing ontology by owl:import is a better choice than reusing by URI reference. So, I need to consider importing ontology rather than referring to their URIs?

Comment: Yes, you need to take that into account